# Which DB to choose in case queries are not defined. Filtering based on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, database, analytics

We have a Admin Portal which is used to manage the sites. In one tenant we have say around 20 - 30 million sites. We show say the following site details -

```
**Site Name Site Url Site Owner StorageUsed StorageQuota Site Visits Site Viewed NumOfFiles CreatedBy CreationSource**
```

Now we give functionality of sorting on one of the column but user can filter by any number of column and in any order (order won't matter in our case). For example an incoming query could be some thing like -

```
Where owner = "owner1" and createdby = "owner2" and siteVisits> 1000 
order by SiteUrl

Or

Where CreationSource = "Chrome" and StorageUsed > 1000 and SiteOwner = "owner3" and StoragetQuota > 2000
order by SiteName
```

Choose any combination. Now you see we don't have defined queries here and user can come, can filter on any column and sort by any column. Currently we are using SQL and we have index on every filterable and sortable columns. We can't use Composite index here as we just can't go and create index for each and every combination. Even if we restrict user that you can only filter in a particular order say left to right, there will be so many combinations and hence indexes and may be more columns will be added to this table(rare though) but will increase the number of indexes exponentially. Can't afford it. We know that SQL server uses [Hash / Merge join](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2115/understanding-sql-server-physical-joins/)  which is not exactly O(n*m) and are better.

Now is there anything else we can do here? We are really open to explore any other known DB to solve this problem. We explored ES but for did not see any benefit there.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to create the query using dynamic sql and have to deal with security (sql injection) and performance, take a look at SSAS and create a cube.

Two dimensions (site and storage) and one fact table.

Comment: Thanks, I did not get you exactly what you are trying to tell me here @MLeblanc. Can you explain in detail. Sql injection and other security things, I can take care.

Comment: sql injection is when you let the user enter text that you'll use "as is" to generate a sql query, without validating the input.  example:  declare @s varchar(max) = 'select * from table where field = '''+@parameter+''';' exec (@s); Think of what will happen if the user set the param to  "null ; -- exec sp_MSforeachdb @command1='drop database ?' .  You don't want that happen. Use parametrized query with  sp_executesql and pay attention for the input.  But i'll stick with SSAS,it comes with SQL server and offer great flexibility compare to dyn. sql. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Ok. Thanks @Mleblanc. This is for the security. My question was more around how to make it efficient. Is SSAS cubes are helpful here? Why you chose site and storage as dimension? I am also reading more around SSAS after your comment but appreciate if you can elaborate more which can help me understand how SSAS is helpful to make random queries efficient.